# System.Text.Json: Get the property name in a custom converter

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, system.text.json, asp.net-core-5.0

Deserializing using `JsonSerialize.DeserializeAsync` and a custom converter, e.g.

```
public class MyStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here I would get *all* `string` properties, which is kind of okay, though is there any way to check the property name for a given value, e.g. something like this, where to process only the `Body` property:

```
class MyMailContent 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class MyStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.PropertyName.Equals("Body"))
        {
            var s = reader.GetString();
            //do some process with the string value
            return s;
        }

        return reader.GetString();
    }
}
```

Or is there some other way to single out a given property?

*Note, I am looking for a solution using `System.Text.Json`.*

Comment: Are you implying without saying it that you don't want to decorate the `Body` property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyStringJsonConverter))]`?

Comment: @Jimi -- No I wasn't. I still would like to have a solution not depending on decorating properties all over the place, but I haven't found how decorating a property would make the converter kick in only on a decorated one. Please provide an answer for that.

Comment: If you are looking for the name of the parent property when reading the property value, or more generally the ***path*** to the current value, then it seems that `System.Text.Json` does not make that available.  It tracks it internally -- it's in  [`ReadStack.JsonPath()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/798949a6f8013fc457cecca1f291a930670cd913/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs#L234) but `ReadStack` is internal and never passed to applications code.

Comment: Also, Jimi asked, *Are you implying that you don't want to decorate the Body property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyStringJsonConverter))]`* and you answered, *No I wasn't.*  So, given that you are willing to decorate `Body` with some converter attribute, can't you use a specific converter for that property?  If not, might you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc IIRC, you can deserialize the whole thing *manually*, in a `while(reader.Read())` loop, check whether `reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName`, then read the next value. I'm not sure it's worth it here, since - as it appears - the custom deserialization always applies to the same property, so decorating that property seems a better choice.

Comment: @dbc -- Thanks for commenting. Your first comment answer my main question, so posting that as an answer would probably be good for future users. Your second comment, I did answer Jimi saying _using decoration could be one solution, I just haven't found how-to for it to only fire on a single property_, and asked them to post such solution.

Comment: @dbc When `.TokenType = JsonTokenType.PropertyName`, then `reader.GetString();` should return the property name (cannot test right now, it's an IIRC).

Comment: @Jimi - that's true, but in a `JsonConverter<string>` the `TokenType` will generally not be `JsonTokenType.PropertyName`, unless OP is writing a converter to deserialize a complex object as a single string.  I *think* what OP wants to do here is to create a converter that preprocesses every string -- e.g. by trimming it -- but has different logic for certain string properties.  But I'm not sure and so a [mcve] would clarify things.

Comment: @dbc I actually meant a `JsonConverter<MyMailContent>` with *deserialize the whole thing manually*, but (always IIRC) `JsonConverter<string>` should also include `TokenType.PropetyName`. -- I'll test it when I can (but, you know this stuff better than I do...).

Comment: @dbc  Right, I mean, always handling the `reader` directly (given the *nature* of the class shown here).

Comment: @Ason - *I just haven't found how-to for it to only fire on a single property* -- you know you can just apply [`[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(MyBodyStringJsonConverter))]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-5.0) to `public string Body { get; set; }`, and it will only fire for the `Body` string property, right?

Comment: @dbc -- I didn't know, and while searching all over didn't find one could do that for a single property.

Comment: @Jimi -- I tested using `reader.read()`, and with that one can actually step through all properties/values, exactly what I asked for, so please do provide an answer with a sample doing that, and I will spend a bounty on it. Still, what "dbc" posted, decorate a single property might be more performant/simpler in some cases, though in my solution we do a lot of caching, so even if parsing the whole property list is less performant, we most of the time use a cached object where it matters much less.

Comment: Well, since you seem to have it already sorted out, you can post it yourself. I'll delete the comments. -- If you mean to implement what's called *polymorphic deserialization* (System.Text.Json is still missing some features that are commonly used in Json.Net), thus handling `[Utf8JsonReader].Read()` directly, possibly with a custom `JsonConverter<Class>`. -- I'll set a watch on this question, to add an alternative solution, eventually.

Comment: @Jimi -- So I did, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Text.Json does not make the parent property name, or more generally the [**path**](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to the current value, available inside [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Read_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_).  This information is tracked internally --  it's in [`ReadStack.JsonPath()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/798949a6f8013fc457cecca1f291a930670cd913/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs#L234) -- but [`ReadStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/798949a6f8013fc457cecca1f291a930670cd913/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs) is internal and never passed to applications code.

However, as explained in *[Registration sample - [JsonConverter] on a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-property)*, you can apply your `MyStringJsonConverter` directly to `public string Body { get; set; }` by using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-5.0):

```
class MyMailContent 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyStringJsonConverter))]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

By doing this, `MyStringJsonConverter.Read()` and `.Write()` will fire only for `MyMailContent.Body`.  Even if you have some overall `JsonConverter<string>` in [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Read_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_), the converter applied to the property will [take precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#converter-registration-precedence):

> During serialization or deserialization, a converter is chosen for each JSON element in the following order, listed from highest priority to lowest:
>
> - `[JsonConverter]` applied to a property.
> - A converter added to the `Converters` collection.
> - `[JsonConverter]` applied to a custom value type or POCO.

(Note this differs partially from [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#JsonConverter) where converters applied to types supersede converters in settings.)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659071/system-text-json-get-the-property-name-in-a-custom-converter?noredirect=1#comment119593287_67659071), and with his approval, I post a wiki answer using his suggested solution, and anyone who has more to contribute, please feel free to do so.

In most cases the accepted answer is a good one, though if one still need to process one or more specific properties by their property name, here is one way to do that.

```
public class MyMailContent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class MyMailContentJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyMailContent>
{
    public override MyMailContent Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        var mailContent = new MyMailContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return mailContent;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                var propertyName = reader.GetString();

                reader.Read();

                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        mailContent.Name = reader.GetString();
                        break;

                    case "Subject":
                        mailContent.Subject = reader.GetString();
                        break;

                    case "Body":
                        string body = reader.GetString();
                        //do some process on body here
                        mailContent.Body = body;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyMailContent mailcontent, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

private static JsonSerializerOptions _jsonDeserializeOptions = new()
{
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
    Converters =
    {
        new MyMailContentJsonConverter()
    }
};
```

And use it like this

```
var jsonstring = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyMailContent
{
    Name = "some name",
    Subject = "some subject",
    Body = "some body"
});

var MailContent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyMailContent>(jsonstring, _jsonDeserializeOptions);
```